# howto install gems in $HOME instead of "/" with bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

by default bundler install gems into system root.
but I want to install gems into $HOME.
how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to edit your ~/.gemrc file and add to it:

```
gem: --local
```

Comment: `gemrc` file is a lot more awesome than people realize. `~/.gemrc` and `/etc/gemrc` can fix a lot of things.

Comment: the full solution is on the page http://wiki.railsplayground.com/railsplayground/show/How+to+install+gems+and+non+root+user

Comment: Shouldn't that be `--user-install`?